# Как с помощью php можно изменить размер изображения?

Tags: php

Например есть вот такое изображение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью php сделать его размерами 100x100, если это возможно

Comment: http://sanchiz.net/blog/resizing-images-with-php и http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=graph&page=014

Comment: С помощью PHP можно создавать даже GIF анимации из отдельных фреймов. Причём это всё работает со стандартными библиотеками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// файл и новый размер
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// тип содержимого
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// получение нового размера
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// загрузка
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// изменение размера
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// вывод
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Офф документация - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score 4):

По ссылке есть класс для работы с изображениями, в некоторых случаях может быть удобен чтобы не придумывать аналог самостоятельно: http://blog.ivru.net/?id=242
Умеет ресайзить изображения а так же сохранять копию оригинального файла в архив если включена соответствующая опция в настройках(все настройки в основном классе библиотеки)

Кроме того умеет чистить архив от старых фотографий если включена соответствующая опция.

Умеет привязываться к элементу, что удобно для детальных карточек. То есть библиотека будет учитывать id например товара и для каждого товара выводить и сохранять изображения отдельно. Изображений у одного элемента может быть несколько, в этом случаи они могут быть выведены как слайдер.

Размеры до которых пережимать изображение так же находятся в настройках, в случаи необходимости можно применить персональные настройки доя отдельно взятой фотографии.
На той же странице по ссылке пример ajax back end файла который организует загрузку новых изображений и удаление при нажатии кнопки, а так же пример скрипта для детальной страницы на которой производится работа с изображениями.
Использовать достаточно просто

$img = new imageProcessor(тут_адрес загруженного файла);//класс сам разбирает формат загружаемого изображения и создаёт по нему ресурс библиотеки gd

$img->resaze();//пережимаем ранее подгруженый в gd файл

$img->saveToJPG();//сохраняем как JPG при этом сохранится исходник в архив если включена опция в настройках

Библиотека не использует базу данных, поэтому работы с метаданными в ней на момент написания ответа не было(может в будущем появится), поэтому рассматривайте для использования если Вам нужно только с изображениями работать и нет необходимости работать с метаданными для них.